Excel Parent Child Relationship and Part Level
Any help is appreciated on this issue. I originally came here to get help on this and was able to find a solution that has worked up until now.
To reference the original post here is the link:
Excel Formula Assigning Parent Part Number to a Child
Here is the link to the Excel Spreadsheet with the current codes being used:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au53oWRKuRfD9kanfyQ62uW30r1V
Again, I will restate that it has worked up until now and I need to get a solution to fix the problem. So let me explain what is going on:
We start by entering in a Bill of Materials (BOM) information for parts on the first tab ("Engineering Release").




A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K




5
Item No.
Part No.
Description



Qty.

UM

Dispo.


6
1
D-008-165-044
ROCKER BACK JOURNAL BEARING



1

EA

Repair


7
1.2
152B2157
JOURNAL PAD



1

EA

Repair


8
1.2.3
159H610
PAD SHIM



1

EA

New


9
1.2.5
1/4-20 X 3/4 LG
S.H.C.S.



3

EA

New


10
1.3
152B2158
JOURNAL PAD



1

EA

Repair


11
1.3.3
159H610
PAD SHIM



1

EA

New


12
1.3.5
1/4-20 X 3/4 LG
S.H.C.S.



3

EA

New


13
1.4
D-027-165-047
JOURNAL PAD MODIFICATION



1

EA

Repair


14
1.4.3
159H610
PAD SHIM



1

EA

New


15
1.4.5
1/4-20 X 3/4 LG
S.H.C.S.



3

EA

New


16
1.4.6
1/8 FF-S
PIPE NIPPLE



1

EA

New


17
1.4.7
1/8 DD-S
90 DEG. ELBOW FEMALE



1

EA

New


18
1.4.8
1/4 PTF
PIPE PLUG



1

EA

New


19
1.4.9
C-202
COMM'L



2

EA

New


20
1.4.10
6-32 X 1/4 LG
B.H.C.S.



2

EA

New


21
1.4.11
B-026-155
THERMOCOUPLE



1

EA

New


22
1.5
D-027-165-048
JOURNAL PAD MODIFICATION



1

EA

New


23
1.5.3
159H610
PAD SHIM



1

EA

New


24
1.5.5
1/4-20 X 3/4 LG
S.H.C.S.



3

EA

New


25
1.5.6
1/8 FF-S
PIPE NIPPLE



1

EA

New


26
1.5.7
1/8 DD-S
90 DEG. ELBOW FEMALE



1

EA

New


27
1.5.8
1/4 PTF
PIPE PLUG



1

EA

New


28
1.5.9
C-202
COMM'L



2

EA

New


29
1.5.10
6-32 X 1/4 LG
B.H.C.S.



2

EA

New


30
1.5.11
B-026-155
THERMOCOUPLE



1

EA

New


31
1.6
159A601-1
FLOATING SEAL (FWD)



1

EA

Repair


32
1.6.1
1/4-20 X 2 1/2 LG
S.H.C.S.



2

EA

New


33
1.6.2
3/16 DIA. X 1/2 LG
DOWEL



2

EA

New


34
1.6.3
5/16 DIA. X 1/2 LG
DOWEL



1

EA

New


35
1.7
159A601-2
FLOATING SEAL (AFT)



1

EA

Repair


36
1.7.1
1/4-20 X 2 1/2 LG
S.H.C.S.



2

EA

New


37
1.7.2
3/16 DIA. X 1/2 LG
DOWEL



2

EA

New


38
1.7.3
5/16 DIA. X 1/2 LG
DOWEL



1

EA

New


39
1.8
D-031-194
END PLATE (FWD)



1

EA

Repair


40
1.9
D-031-195
END PLATE (AFT)



1

EA

Repair


41
1.1
COMM L
WIRE CLIPS



8

EA

New


42
1.11
#6-32 X 1/4 LG
B.H.C.S.



8

EA

New


43
1.12
159B1680
PIPE ASSEMBLY



2

EA

New


44
1.13
1/2-13 X 1 3/4 LG
S.H.C.S.



24

EA

New


45
1.14
159H613-2
WASHER



8

EA

New



Column A (Item No.) is what is used to assign the parent part to a child part and determine what part level in the assembly it is. For example:
Assembly = 1 is the assembly and its level is 0,
Component 1 = 1.1 is the component part to 1 (assembly) and its level is 1,
Sub-Component 1 = 1.1.1 is the sub-component part to 1.1 (component 1) and its level is 2,
Component 2 = 1.2 is the component part to 1 (assembly) and its level is 1,
Sub-Component 2 = 1.2.1 is the sub-component part to 1.2 (component 2) and its level is 2,
Sub-Sub-Component = 1.2.1.1 is the sub-sub-component part to 1.2.1 (sub-component 2) and its level is 3,
etc....
On the second tab ("BOMUploadRelease") I have everything from the first sheet automated with code to fill out a template sheet that gets uploaded to our ERP system.




A
C
O
S




1
PartNo
Description
Level
Parent


2
D-008-165-044.R
ROCKER BACK JOURNAL BEARING
0



3
152B2157.R
JOURNAL PAD
1
D-008-165-044.R


4
159H610.N
PAD SHIM
2
152B2157.R


5
1/4-20 X 3/4 LG.N
S.H.C.S.
2
152B2157.R


6
152B2158.R
JOURNAL PAD
1
D-008-165-044.R


7
159H610.N
PAD SHIM
2
152B2157.R


8
1/4-20 X 3/4 LG.N
S.H.C.S.
2
152B2157.R


9
D-027-165-047.R
JOURNAL PAD MODIFICATION
1
D-008-165-044.R


10
159H610.N
PAD SHIM
2
152B2157.R


11
1/4-20 X 3/4 LG.N
S.H.C.S.
2
152B2157.R


12
1/8 FF-S.N
PIPE NIPPLE
2
D-027-165-047.R


13
1/8 DD-S.N
90 DEG. ELBOW FEMALE
2
D-027-165-047.R


14
1/4 PTF.N
PIPE PLUG
2
D-027-165-047.R


15
C-202.N
COMM'L
2
D-027-165-047.R


16
6-32 X 1/4 LG.N
B.H.C.S.
3
D-027-165-047.R


17
B-026-155.N
THERMOCOUPLE
3
D-027-165-047.R


18
D-027-165-048.N
JOURNAL PAD MODIFICATION
1
D-008-165-044.R


19
159H610.N
PAD SHIM
2
152B2157.R


20
1/4-20 X 3/4 LG.N
S.H.C.S.
2
152B2157.R


21
1/8 FF-S.N
PIPE NIPPLE
2
D-027-165-047.R


22
1/8 DD-S.N
90 DEG. ELBOW FEMALE
2
D-027-165-047.R


23
1/4 PTF.N
PIPE PLUG
2
D-027-165-047.R


24
C-202.N
COMM'L
2
D-027-165-047.R


25
6-32 X 1/4 LG.N
B.H.C.S.
3
D-027-165-047.R


26
B-026-155.N
THERMOCOUPLE
3
D-027-165-047.R


27
159A601-1.R
FLOATING SEAL (FWD)
1
D-008-165-044.R


28
1/4-20 X 2 1/2 LG.N
S.H.C.S.
2
159A601-1.R


29
3/16 DIA. X 1/2 LG.N
DOWEL
2
159A601-1.R


30
5/16 DIA. X 1/2 LG.N
DOWEL
2
159A601-1.R


31
159A601-2.R
FLOATING SEAL (AFT)
1
D-008-165-044.R


32
1/4-20 X 2 1/2 LG.N
S.H.C.S.
2
159A601-1.R


33
3/16 DIA. X 1/2 LG.N
DOWEL
2
159A601-1.R


34
5/16 DIA. X 1/2 LG.N
DOWEL
2
159A601-1.R


35
D-031-194.R
END PLATE (FWD)
1
D-008-165-044.R


36
D-031-195.R
END PLATE (AFT)
1
D-008-165-044.R


37
COMM L.N
WIRE CLIPS
1
D-008-165-044.R


38
#6-32 X 1/4 LG.N
B.H.C.S.
2
D-008-165-044.R


39
159B1680.N
PIPE ASSEMBLY
2
D-008-165-044.R


40
1/2-13 X 1 3/4 LG.N
S.H.C.S.
2
D-008-165-044.R


41
159H613-2.N
WASHER
2
D-008-165-044.R



In this sheet is where the codes are. The part number gets assigned a ".(letter)" added to the end of the part number from the first tab based off the selection of the "Dispo" Column on the first tab. The Level column on tab 2 ("BOMUploadRelease") is assigned based off Column A (Item No.) and the Parent column on tab 2 ("BOMUploadRelease") is assigned based off Column A (Item No.) but inputs the parent part number from the (PartNo) column on tab 2 ("BOMUploadRelease").
The first issue is the levels being assigned. The current code was working fine until we had a larger BOM and used double digits like 1.5.11 and due to the double digit "11" after the dot it gives it a level of 3 when it should still be a 2. Basically, for every "." in the string from Column A (Item No.) on the first tab ("Engineering Release") would be a level so 0 "."'s would be a level 0, 1 "." would be a level 1, 2 "."'s would be a level 2, 3 "."'s would be a level 3, etc.
The code being used for the part levels issue is:
=IF('Engineering Release'!A6<>"",LEN('Engineering Release'!A6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE('Engineering Release'!A6,".","")),"")

For the second issue, it is the parent number being assigned incorrectly when there is the same subcomponent part number in the BOM but 2 different parent component numbers that use the same subcomponent part number. It will always pull the first parent part number for all the subcomponents rather then assigning then to the correct one.
What it looks like now:

What it should be with the corrected errors in red text:

The code being used for the assignment of the parent part number is:
=LET(x, XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(A2,".",-1),
    'Engineering Release'!$B$6:$B$62,
    'Engineering Release'!$A$6:$A$62),
 y, 'Engineering Release'!$K$6:$K$62,IFERROR( XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(x,".",-1),
             TEXT('Engineering Release'!$A$6:$A$62,"@"),
             'Engineering Release'!$B$6:$B$62 &"." &IFS (y="Ref.","REF", y="Repair","R", y="Reuse","U", y="Modify","M", y="New","N", y="Outsource","O")),""))          

Any and all help is appreciated and wanted. Please refer to the spreadsheet in the link, the pictures showing how it is not vs how it should be, and the codes being used.

Note that your issue 1 is caused by a wrong in your formula. it currrently says: =IF('Engineering Release'!A6<>"",LEN(SUBSTITUTE('Engineering Release'!A6,".",""))-1,"") while in you question you wrote a formula that would calculate correctly: =IF('Engineering Release'!A6<>"",LEN('Engineering Release'!A6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE('Engineering Release'!A6,".","")),"")

I had help with that formula from the first time I came here because I was stuck. It worked so far on simple BOMs but this more complex BOM not so much. I see why it is a problem though.

You could use the following formula for Level in O2:
=LET(a,DROP(TOCOL('Engineering Release'!A:A,1),4),LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a,".",)))

This spills the size of the number of parts used in the Engineering Release, so make sure to delete all values (formulas) from the cells below.
Then for Parent in S2 you could use:
=XLOOKUP(O2-1,O$1:O1,A$1:A1,"",,-1)


A bit off-topic:
You could simplify your formula in BomUploadRelease!A2 drastically:
old formula: =IF('Engineering Release'!K6:K6="Repair",CONCATENATE('Engineering Release'!B6:B6,".R"),IF('Engineering Release'!K6:K6="Reuse",CONCATENATE('Engineering Release'!B6:B6,".U"),IF('Engineering Release'!K6:K6="Modify",CONCATENATE('Engineering Release'!B6:B6,".M"),IF('Engineering Release'!K6:K6="Ref.",CONCATENATE('Engineering Release'!B6:B6,".F"),IF('Engineering Release'!K6:K6="New",CONCATENATE('Engineering Release'!B6:B6,".N"), "")))))
new formula: =DROP(TOCOL('Engineering Release'!B:B,1),1)&"."&SWITCH(DROP(TOCOL('Engineering Release'!K:K,1),1),"Repair","R","Reuse","U","Modify","M","Ref.","F","New","N")
Or Beta: =DROP('Engineering Release'!B:.B,5)&"."&SWITCH(DROP('Engineering Release'!K:.K,5),"Repair","R","Reuse","U","Modify","M","Ref.","F","New","N")
And your formula in BomUploadRelease!C2:
old formula: =IF(ISBLANK('Engineering Release'!C6:F6), "", 'Engineering Release'!C6:F6)
new (I don't see why you reference up to column F since these are
merged and therefore won't contain data): =TOCOL(DROP('Engineering Release'!C:C,5),1)
or Beta: =DROP('Engineering Release'!C:.C,5)

on topic again:
if you implemented the changes above, you could spill your Parent using:
=MAP(A2#,O2#,LAMBDA(PartNo,Level,XLOOKUP(Level-1,O2:Level,A2:PartNo,"",,-1)))


Nice P.b. May I ask what is the 'Beta' syntax C:.C? Thank you.

Thanks. The . means up to the last used cell. C.:.C would be from first used up to last used. Unfortunately you can't write C6:.C (yet?). If you're on the insiders program and using Beta Channel this is a new activated feature, which will eventually come to the regular users as well, once tested succesfully.

@nkalvi See more here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-trimrange-and-accompanying-trim-references/ba-p/4230202#:~:text=The%20TRIMRANGE%20function%20removes%20empty,text%20entered%20into%20column%20A.

Not yet available on Mac Beta (v. 2408 still). Thanks again.

Wow... Thank you. I am on the road this weekend but I will try all that out when I get back to the office. I have never dealt with spills and never seen it either so I am very interested in using it. I will let you know as soon as I can

@JoshuaJohnson spilling opens doors to creating dynamic solutions. They update live when changing/adding data.

That is good to know. I need to learn this then. I am trying to automate as much of our manual data entry into excel sheets as possible and switch to utilize the ERP system more but some processes like this one still requires the initial excel spreadsheet to do the work to convert everything over for the upload into the ERP system with minimum data entry.

@JoshuaJohnson if you worry about the order of Engineering Release data, this may be an easy fix: =LET(a,SORT(""&DROP(TOCOL('Engineering Release'!A:A,1),4)),LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a,".",)))

If you have Microsoft 365 (please let me know otherwise), please enter this in the first cell in BOMUploadRelease:


Using Name Manager, define BOMUpRel with the code below
This user defined function takes the data range and result col needed as the input
With col_num as a parameter you can place column in positions needed (as shown in the example)

=LAMBDA(eng_data, col_num,
    LET(
        header, TAKE(eng_data, 1),
        data, DROP(eng_data, 1),
        item_no, INDEX(data, , 1),
        part_no, INDEX(data, , 2) &
            SWITCH(
                INDEX(data, , XMATCH("Dispo.", header)),
                "Repair", "R",
                "Reuse", "U",
                "Modify", "M",
                "Ref", "F",
                "New", "N"
            ),
        level, LEN(item_no) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(item_no, ".", "")),
        parent_item_no, TEXTBEFORE(item_no, ".", level),
        parent_part_no, IF(
            level,
            XLOOKUP(parent_item_no, item_no & "", part_no, "not found"),
            ""
        ),
        result, HSTACK(part_no, INDEX(data, , 3), level, parent_part_no),
        CHOOSECOLS(result, col_num)
    )
)


Clear existing values in BOMUploadRelease
Enter =BOMUpRel('Engineering Release'!A5:K45, col_num) in the first cell of each column
Since the col_num parameter is used with CHOOSECOLS, to get multiple columns, enter the 1-4 as an array within {}; for example ``=BOMUpRel('Engineering Release'!A5:K45,{1,2,3,4})` will return all columns.


Result:


I have used descriptive names for variables, please let me know if detailed explanation is needed.

Yes we are using 365. I use the desktop apps for everything except a few SharePoint documents. This excel workbook is through the desktop app. I will try the code and get back with you due to being on the road right now. If I can stop and log in remotely I will try it. Thank you so much for the help.

That’s good. LAMBDA etc. will work then.
